# I have make a histogram and I want to increase binwidths

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, sharex=False, sharey=False)
df_russel_fee.hist(column='fee', by='fiscal_year',xlabelsize=10,figsize=(0,0),bins=50,ax=axes)
plt.suptitle('Russel fee histogram', x=0.5, y=0.99, ha='center', fontsize='xx-large')
fig.text(0.5, 0.04, 'value', ha='center',fontsize='xx-large')
fig.text(0, 0.5, 'frequency', va='center', rotation='vertical',fontsize='xx-large')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15,6)
```

[image]

Comment: You can specify either the total number of bins or the specific bin boundaries with the parameters `bins`. It's currently set to 50 in your code. Try setting it to something lower, like 30.

Answer (score -1):

Currently you now specify 50 bins. If you want to increase the WIDTH of the bins (and decrease the NUMBER of bins), you can just specify a lower number of bins (e.g. `bins=25`). So change the line to:

```
df_russel_fee.hist(column='fee', by='fiscal_year',xlabelsize=10, figsize=(0,0),bins=25,ax=axes)
```

If you want to keep the same number of bins, but make the figures WIDER, you can change the `figsize` parameter in the same line. The tuple behind `figsize=` specifies (width, height).

Comment: If I don't want to decrease the number of bins I just want to increase the width of the bins

Comment: If you don't decrease the number of bins and you don't widen your figure, then your bins would just overlap and you wouldn't see the individual bars anymore...